# Does ms graph API support outlook on office 365 on Germany endpoint?

Tags: azure, cloud, microsoft-graph-api

I found that graph API in Germany endpoint seems not to support

```
GET /users/<id>/mailFolders/delta
```

it returns

```
**400**
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidIdMalformed",
        "message": "Id is malformed.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "cf713386-f050-40b4-b987-43cc2384eade",
            "date": "2017-12-12T07:13:10"
        }
    }
}
```

However it works fine at

```
GET /users/<id>/mailFolders
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I had been in the same trouble, but I resolved.
Your request to:

```
GET /users/<id>/mailFolders/delta
```

is not correct, I think.

I guess that this mail folder `delta` was made by you, doesn't it?

To specify a mail folder, you need to use folder `id`, **not display name**.
Though you might already get the folder id, you can get the folder id by sending a request

```
GET /users/<id>/mailFolders
```

Note: Actually, we can get folder_ids via powershell:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics
```

cmdlet on Exchange. However, these `folder_id` are malformed in ms-graph request. So you need to use the id which you can get as described above.

Comment: Hi, tsekine, thanks for reply, but delta is a function for mailFolders,
you can see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview,